# How to clear a specific cache in iOS swift WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, caching, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` app which i will like to clear a specific cache when image is uploaded .

When i upload an image, the name remains same but the old image will be override with new one, like old image is `logo.png`, new image will be renamed with `logo.png` also. But because of cache users will still be seeing the old image.

I have below line of code to clear cache once image has been uploaded and it working fine, but my only problem now is that all cached data is being cleared also.

Is there any way i can clear cache for just the image was uploaded, maybe by passing the image name?

Or just clear cache for images?

```
static func clearCache(){
        let cacheURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory( at: cacheURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            for file in directoryContents {
                print("CACHE = ", file)
                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: file)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    debugPrint("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
                }

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

From the loop i got this

> CACHE = 
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BFEB788B-9EA4-4921-A902-230869CAC814/Library/Caches/com.myapp.ios.sellers/
>   CACHE = 
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BFEB788B-9EA4-4921-A902-230869CAC814/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/
>   CACHE = 
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BFEB788B-9EA4-4921-A902-230869CAC814/Library/Caches/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent/
>   CACHE = 
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BFEB788B-9EA4-4921-A902-230869CAC814/Library/Caches/WebKit/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to find the file you want to remove when you are in the for loop loop for files. Remove that specific image when the for loop hits. Right now that for loop removes all cache in directoryContents.

Comment: I updated my question with what i got from the loop. How do i get the image?